# Como criar e remover div´s com inputs dinamicamente com jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando criar e remover dinamicamente `div´s` para um form que tenho, já fiz usando tabela, mas agora me foi solicitado `div´s`.
Tentei fazer uma adaptação mas não consegui, o que preciso é criar um botão para inserir as `div´s` e um para remove-las se necessário.

O meu formulário completo ésse:

```
<section>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <header class="text-center margin-top-20">
               <h4 align="center">Preencha os campos para gerar a impressão do termo</h4>
            </header>
            <br>                    
            <header class="text-center margin-top-20">
               <h4 align="center">Informações Autorizador</h4>
            </header>
            <br>                    
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
               <form id="frmCadastro" class="sky-form clearfix" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="NomeAutorizador" id="NomeAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Nome">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="NacAutorizador" id="NacAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Nacionalidade">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="ProfAutorizador" id="ProfAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Profisssão">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="CPFAutorizador" id="CPFAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="CPF">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="RGAutorizador" id="RGAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="RG">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="EndAutorizador" id="EndAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Endereço">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="CidadeAutorizador" id="CidadeAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Cidade">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="UFAutorizador" id="UFAutorizador" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="UF">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <header class="text-center margin-top-20">
                     <h4 align="center">Informações Autorizado</h4>
                  </header>
                  <br/>                       
                  // ESSA ROW QUE PRECISO INSERIR 
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="NomeAutorizado" id="NomeAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Nome">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="CPFAutorizado" id="CPFAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="CPF">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="RGAutorizado" id="RGAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="RG">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="BancoAutorizado" id="BancoAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Banco">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="AgenciaAutorizado" id="AgenciaAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Agência">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="CCAutorizado" id="CCAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Conta Corrente">
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                     </div> 
                  </div>
                  // ESSA ROW QUE PRECISO INSERIR**

                  <header class="text-center margin-top-20">
                     <h4 align="center">Local</h4>
                  </header>
                  <br/>    
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                           <select name="Unicoop" class="form-control pointer required" id="Unicoop">
                              <option value="0">Unicoop</option>
                              <?php foreach ($ResUnicoop as $Unicoop) { ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $Unicoop->IdUnicoop ?>"><?php echo $Unicoop->Nome ?></option>
                              <?php } ?>
                           </select>
                           <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>

               </form>

              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary  pull-right btn-block">IMPRIMIR</button>
                 </div>
              </div>                                   


               <div id="msgBusca" style="padding: 10px;">
                  <!-- Mensagens --> 
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Tenho várias `rows` nesse form, mas a que preciso inserir a mais é essa aqui:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="BancoAutorizado" id="BancoAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Banco">
    <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="AgenciaAutorizado" id="AgenciaAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Agência">
    <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="CCAutorizado" id="CCAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Conta Corrente">
    <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
 </div>
</div>
```

O meu form tem essa identificação:

```
<form id="frmCadastro" class="sky-form clearfix" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
```

Não vou postar o que tentei fazer porque sinceramente não vai ter utilidade nenhuma.

Comment: Estava assistindo essa videoaula ontem, espero que te ajude: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKKR0sEMGE8&list=PLcHPNq67CaVnHwfOeK9-7n57aOV6orMSO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sugiro que crie uma `div` para *empacotar* as duas `.row` que você quer adicionar. Por quê? Porque irá tornar viável a adição das novas `.row`. Como elas estão *soltas* no meio do `<form>`, seria muito complicado adicionar as novas.

Eu criei uma `div` com `id="dadosbanco"` e coloquei as duas `.row` dentro dela. Desta forma teremos essa `div` como referência e o trabalho se torna extremamente mais simples.

Criei um botão <kbd>Adicionar</kbd> para adicionar as novas `.row` e um botão <kbd>Remover</kbd> em cada linha para remover a respectiva linha. Coloquei também na função um código que impede que todas as linhas sejam removidas, devendo ficar pelo menos uma.

Veja o exemplo abaixo que você deve adaptar ao seu Bootstrap:

```js
var cloneform = $('#dadosbanco').html();
$(document).on('click','.remDiv, .addDiv', function(e){
   var thisClass = Array.from(e.target.classList);
   ~thisClass.indexOf('remDiv')
      ?
      ($('.remDiv').length > 1
         ?
         $(this).closest('.row').prev().add($(this).closest('.row')).remove()
         :
         0)
      :
      $('#dadosbanco').append(cloneform);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmCadastro" class="sky-form clearfix" action="" method="post" target="_blank">

OUTRAS DIVS E CONTEÚDO AQUI

<div id="dadosbanco">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" name="NomeAutorizado[]" id="NomeAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Nome">
         <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" name="CPFAutorizado[]" id="CPFAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="CPF">
         <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" name="RGAutorizado[]" id="RGAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="RG">
         <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" name="BancoAutorizado[]" id="BancoAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Banco">
         <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" name="AgenciaAutorizado[]" id="AgenciaAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Agência">
         <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" name="CCAutorizado[]" id="CCAutorizado" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Conta Corrente">
         <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <input type="button" value="Remover" class="remDiv btn btn-styles" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br />

<input type="button" value="Adicionar" class="addDiv" />

<br />
MAIS DIVS E CONTEÚDO AQUI

</form>
```

**NOTAS**

- Adicionado `[]` aos nomes dos campos para serem enviados em forma de array.
- Em relação aos `id`'s dos campos, caso não forem ser usados, sugiro que os remova, pois ao criar uma nova linha, os `id`'s irão se repetir e isso dará problema caso for usar. Sugiro que em vez de `id`'s, use classes.

Comment: Olá @ÐvÐ, obrigado pela grande ajuda, mas cometi um erro ao postar a minha pergunta, tenho várias "rows" e coloquei somente a que gostaria de inserir, quando clico no inserir está inserindo mas inserindo a minha primeira row com campos que não tem nada a ver com os que preciso, me perdoe a falha.

Comment: @adventistapr Não tem problema. Já vi a atualização da resposta. Então você quer adicionar, neste caso, duas .row, é isso?

Comment: Boa tarde @ÐvÐ, isso mesmo.

Comment: @adventistapr Atualizada. Abs!

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado @ÐvÐ, muito bom mesmo.

Comment: Seu código não funciona ao implementar as classes .btn e .btn-styles junto à classe .remDev para um input ou button em bootstrap 4, o botão de remover passa a funcionar como um botão de adicionar mais uma .row.

Comment: @EliseuB. Código arrumado. Na questão era previsto que os botões possuíssem apenas 1 classe (remDiv ou addDiv). Mas ajustei para o caso de ter outras classes juntas.

Comment: Até mais legível, obrigado por isso =)

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar codigo dinamicamente com jQuery, pode usar o metodo `append`.

```
$("#frmCadastro").append('<div class="row"> ... </div>');
```

Ou se quiser mudar o conteudo, pode usar o metodo `html`

```
$("#frmCadastro").html('<div class="row"> ... </div>');
```

Para remover o ultimo elemento do form, pode usar `remove`

```
$('#frmCadastro').children('div').last().remove();
```

Se quiser remover um elemento especifico, aconselho usar um Id no div.

```
$('#id_div').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Nos `names` dos inputs foram acrescentados colchetes `[]` no final para que os valores sejam salvos em um array.
>
> Os ids dos inputs são diferentes exemplo `id="BancoAutorizado' + x + '` onde x é incrementado a cada adição de divs
>
> var `max_divs` limita o numero do conjunto de divs adicionados

O método `append()` - permite adicionar conteúdo (um seletor, um elemento HTML, uma string HTML ou um objeto jQuery) ao FINAL de um elemento HTML.

**HTML + Biblioteca + Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_divs      = 10; //maximo conjunto de divs
    var wrapper         = $(".row");
    var add_button      = $(".botao_add");
    
    var x = 1; //contador de inseridos
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_divs){ //max input box allowed
            x++; // incrementa contador
            $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="BancoAutorizado[]" id="BancoAutorizado' + x + '" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Banco"><i class="fancy-arrow"></i></div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="AgenciaAutorizado[]" id="AgenciaAutorizado' + x + '" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Agência"><i class="fancy-arrow"></i></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="CCAutorizado[]" id="CCAutorizado' + x + '" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Conta Corrente"><i class="fancy-arrow"></i></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

//-->
</script>

<form id="frmCadastro" class="sky-form clearfix" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
<div class="row">
    <button class="botao_add">Add Mais</button>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="BancoAutorizado[]" id="BancoAutorizado1" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Banco">
    <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="AgenciaAutorizado[]" id="AgenciaAutorizado1" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Agência">
    <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="CCAutorizado[]" id="CCAutorizado1" value="" class="form-control required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Conta Corrente">
    <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> 
 </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $arrayBancos = $_POST['BancoAutorizado'];
  $arrayAgencias = $_POST['AgenciaAutorizado'];
  $arrayCCAutorizados = $_POST['CCAutorizado'];

  print_r($arrayBancos);
  print_r($arrayAgencias);
  print_r($arrayCCAutorizados);
?>
```